# Extract specific portion of text from pdf using Javascript?

Tags: text, extract

I need to do a modification. I am using this code that I found to extract all text in the pdf:

```
<!-- edit this; the PDF file must be on the same domain as this page -->
<iframe id="input" src="your-file.pdf"></iframe>

<!-- embed the pdftotext service as an iframe -->
<iframe id="processor" src="http://hubgit.github.com/2011/11/pdftotext/"></iframe>

<!-- a container for the output -->
<div id="output"></div>

<script>
var input = document.getElementById("input");
var processor = document.getElementById("processor");
var output = document.getElementById("output");

// listen for messages from the processor
window.addEventListener("message", function(event){
  if (event.source != processor.contentWindow) return;

  switch (event.data){
    // "ready" = the processor is ready, so fetch the PDF file
    case "ready":
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
      xhr.open('GET', input.getAttribute("src"), true);
      xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";
      xhr.onload = function(event) {
        processor.contentWindow.postMessage(this.response, "*");
      };
      xhr.send();
    break;

    // anything else = the processor has returned the text of the PDF
    default:
      output.textContent = event.data.replace(/\s+/g, " ");
    break;
  }
}, true);
</script>
```

The output is packed text without any paragraphs. All my pdfs have the word 'Datacover' somewhere in the beginning and follows a big paragraph.

All I want to do is to delete all the text from its begining until the first instance of the word 'Datacover' and also at the front of the word 'Datacover' to show all text until the third instance of '. ' <--(dot with space) and delete all the next text to the end.

Can you help? thanks!

Comment: Can you add an example of how the text looks like and what exactly you want to remove?

Comment: Imagine that there are all possible characters and lines of them before the word 'Datacover' and the same also happen after it.

Comment: Perhaps you could get a match like this instead of removing the data `\bDatacover\b(?:[\s\S]*\. ){3}` https://regex101.com/r/vcfZE1/1

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I need but the limit to 3 instances is not working. https://regex101.com/r/vcfZE1/2  Also how this will fit at the code above?

Comment: My bad, there was a question mark missing in the pattern. It should be like this `\bDatacover\b(?:[\s\S]*?\. ){3}` See https://regex101.com/r/f0RD2I/1 So the text of the PDF is in in `event.data`?

Comment: A thank you!! now is perfect! Yes in event.data!

Comment: I have added it as an answer with an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could match Datacover between word boundaries `\b` and repeat in a non greedy way 3 times matching any char including a newling `[\s\S]*?` until the next occurrence of a dot and space `\.`

```
\bDatacover\b(?:[\s\S]*?\. ){3}
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/f0RD2I/1)

To get the data, you could use

```
event.data.match(regex)
```

For example:

```js
const regex = /\bDatacover\b(?:[\s\S]*?\. ){3}/g;
let event = {
  data: `testhjgjhg hjg jhg jkgh kjhghjkg76t 76 tguygtf yr 6 rt6 gtyut 67 tuy yoty yutyu tyu yutyuit iyut iuytiyu tuiyt Datacover uytuy tuyt uyt uiytuiyt uytutest.
yu tuyt uyt uyt iutiuyt uiy
 yuitui tuyt
test. 
 uiyt uiytuiyt
 uyt ut ui
this is a test. 
sjhdgfjsa. 
hgwryuehrgfhrghw fsdfdfsfs sddsfdfs.`
};

console.log(event.data.match(regex));
```